# Passing parameter values using a href, storing and retrieving them using session only with JSP's

Tags: java, jsp, url-rewriting, httpsession

As opposed to what my question suggests, I completely understand that it is not right to have any form of code in a JSP. But I have an important task to accomplish and this is the scenario : 
    Once a link is clicked, the parameters that are passed, whatever it may be, is being truncated (due to security reasons) and I need to obtain these parameters somehow  after a user has logged in. I am trying to do this using a session.

I have four JSP pages say :

1. routing.jsp
2. intermediateTarget.jsp
3. login.jsp
4. target.jsp

and page with a link and some parameters being passed into it :

```
< a href="router.jsp?p1=s&p2=s123">Click here</a>
```

Once I click this it takes me to `router.jsp` where I create a session and obtain the passed parameters and also set them into the session:

```
<% String param1 = request.getParameter("p1");
   String param2 = request.getParameter("p2");

   HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(true);
   session1.setAttribute("p1", param1);
   session1.setAttribute("p2", param2);
   response.sendRedirect("intermediateTarget.jsp");
 %>
```

`router.jsp` is executed `onload` so it is basically re-directed to `intermediateTarget.jsp`.

Here, I am obtaining the parameters using getAttribute :

```
    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
    String param1 = (String) request.getAttribute("p1");
    String param2 = (String) request.getAttribute("p2");

    String param = request.getParameter("param");
    String lgn = request.getParameter("lgn");

    if (null != param) {
        response.sendRedirect("empLogin.jsp");
    } else if (null != lgn) {
        response.sendRedirect("target.jsp");
    }
```

I have two hidden parameters being passed from the login page and the routing page which are `lgn` and `param` respectively. After checking which ever page the request is gotten from, I would need to redirect it to a `target.jsp` or `login.jsp`.

Basically, after logging in I need to be just able to obtain the same parameters from the session and display it on the target page (like a confirmation that I am in fact able to obtain the parameters that I passed in the link.)

Again, I don't need servlets because this is something that we need to include from our end using only JSP's.

Also, I have read on trying to extract the part of the URL after the `?` and even went into the concept of extracting deeplinks but I'm not getting anywhere.

Sorry if the post seems too long. Just wanted to give a clear idea of my situation and also any other ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't understand why you don't want servlets since it's much clearer and more beautiful code. They are also perfect for this situation.

This has nothing to do with the question but for making your life easier.

If you are using scriptlets which are mostly just disturbing to read I advice you to put 
the scriptlet tag instead for the readability of the code, e.g.

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
    String param1 = request.getParameter("p1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("p2");

    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(true);
    session1.setAttribute("p1", param1);
    session1.setAttribute("p2", param2);
    response.sendRedirect("intermediateTarget.jsp");
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

Now to what I believe is your problem since it wasn't very clear what you wanted.

You are actually storing your variables in the session (which you want to do), but you are accessing them from the request?

For session scoped variables you should call:

```
String param2 = (String)request.getSession(false).getParameter("p2");
// or session1.getParameter("p2"); 
// if you add false where you create the variable.
```

You want to use the false paramenter in getSession because the user must have a session if he/she is logged in and you want to redirect them with a filter instead of creating a new session I assume.

I would prefer to write it like this though

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty param}">
        <c:redirect url="empLogin.jsp"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <c:redirect url="target.jsp"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Hope it answered your question, feel free to comment if I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: I have replaced the scriptlets with the scriptlet tag. Also,I am not very familiar with using JSTL tags which is why I am trying to write them with if-else conditions.

Comment: I am able to obtain the parameters from the session in the `intermediateTarget.jsp` but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: When you say `test="${not empty param}"` do I pass the hidden field name here and then check for the condition ?  
Also, I have two hidden fields in two different jsp's, one on the `router.jsp` and the other on `empLogin.jsp` which I am trying to obtain in the `intermediateTarget.jsp` to check which page the request is being obtained from and `response.sendRedirect` that request to the appropriate jsp's, then obtain these parameters on that jsp page and append it again to the url.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation but I was quite tired and didn't had any environment to test it on as well. the ' ${not empty param}' is an el-expression that is checking if the request or session variable param is there or not, you can use it's value directly with 'code  ${param}' inside of the page to print it out. 
For me scriplets belong somewhere else, I always go for servlet for doing these kind of validations, so I assume it's easier for you do use plain java in scriptlets the jstl is basically an 'code if(param != null)' is the same as the 'code test="${not empty param}"' in el-expression

Comment: It's hard to say since I don't know what you want to do with them, or how you're planning to use them. 

So the explanation is very general

If you have them in the session you don't have to access them just to pass them to next page, they are already there. Because it looked like they were just unused variables that consumes extra resources.

Comment: What I'm trying to do with these parameters is, extract them from the URL and then append them back to the URL after the user logs in and display them in a `target.jsp`.

All this headache because I have an application which truncates the parameters that are passed when the link is clicked initially. So I want to somehow store these parameters and obtain them in the final target page. So basically the link in that I obtain in the final page would need to have the parameters that I obtained from the session appended to it.

Comment: Do you have the option of using el-expression?

Comment: Well I  would need to know el for that which I don't but if there is a solution then I would be happy to figure it out even if it is in el.

Comment: Because then you don't have to send them anywhere, just put them in the session as you did, and on target.jsp you can use it directly as 
<code>${p1} ${p2} </code> or however you name them in setAttribute.

you can add in with normal html aswell
 <code>
<input type="text" value="${p1}" name="param1" id="param1"/>
</code>
or if it HAS to be in the url you can write 
<code>
   "target.jsp?param1=${p1}&param2=${p2}"

</code>
and so on in your redirect

I HATE this comments, can't even do a code block :'(

Comment: I just tried to do the same and it worked. At least I am getting somewhere now. Thanks a lot for your help. :)